# How to display Android Screen (5.0+) to my Mac OS X Laptop?

Tags: screen, chromecast, screencast

This seems similar to several other questions here, but the other questions are outdated. In Android 5.0 there is a native screen casting button (Cast) on the notification drawer for us to cast the screen to a Chromecast.

Is it possible to make our laptop (Mac OS X or otherwise) act as a Chromecast display so that we can press the Cast button on the Android and the screen is shown on the laptop?

I tried `leapcast` but the Android device does not seem to detect it.